# Distributed tracing with kafka spring boot 3 and opentelemetry not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

I wanted to try out tracing between a spring boot 3 Kafka producer and consumer.
I followed the examples from https://spring.io/blog/2022/10/12/observability-with-spring-boot-3
The traceID is added automatically when I make an API call using resttemplate between the producer and consumer, but the Kafka messages do not carry them.
I used the following dependencies

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Kafka producer configuration

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    //typical properties 
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory) {
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> stringStringKafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    stringStringKafkaTemplate.setObservationEnabled(true);//trying out with
    return stringStringKafkaTemplate;
}
```

Sending message

```
    kafkaTemplate.send("topic-1" , "message");
```

On the consumer side :

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic-1", groupId = "group1")
    public void listenGroupFoo(String message) {
        logger.info("Received Message in group foo: " + message);
    }
```

When I check the kafka messages header, there is traceparent header for each message,but I dont see the traceId and spanId in the consumer logs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to make it working by enabling the observation for consumer factory as well.
Change

```
  @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory) {


        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

         //The following code enable observation in the consumer listener  
        factory.getContainerProperties().setObservationEnabled(true);
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);


        return factory;
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Spring for Apache Kafka does not enable tracing by default; see

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#observation

> **Micrometer Observation**

> Using Micrometer for observation is now supported, since version 3.0, for the KafkaTemplate and listener containers.

> Set `observationEnabled` on each component to enable observation; this will disable Micrometer Timers because the timers will now be managed with each observation.

Comment: yes, I read this was able to set it for kafka producer but not for consumer.

Comment: I added some improvements to the docs: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/29cbd0e0eb20493eca0351ad1decda55586681dd

Comment: @GaryRussell does enabling observation in spring kafka somehow disable the default kafka listners metric reportings such as spring_kafka_listener_seconds_count. Reason am asking is that I have some integrations tests which checks that metric and after setting observation to enabled it seems like no reporting is made anymore..

Comment: Yes, as the doc I pointed to above says `>this will disable Micrometer Timers because the timers will now be managed with each observation.`. The timers are then managed by the observation instead (they have different properties). There is no point in maintaining both sets of timers.

Comment: thanks for the reply @GaryRussell. Do you happen to know what these properties will now be called? or perhaps a link to where I can find it?

Comment: I am not able to find any metric that is prefixed with "spring.kafka.listener" at least

Comment: See the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#observation and https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#observation-gen

Comment: @GaryRussell the documentation is not clear on the relevant full property key.  besides setting it with the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory bean, I couldn't find the full key from the links you provided. can you elaborate on that?

Comment: What is not clear? The keys appear in the appendix linked from that chapter https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#observation-gen

Comment: I would expect a application properties to active that flag instead of need to do this programmatically

Comment: There is an open issue requesting the Boot team to add such a property https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/36452

Comment: @GaryRussell the links that you posted are all giving 404. Only the GitHub commit link works.

Comment: Documentation uses different technology since 3.1. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/index.html